# Какие есть способы кэширования данных на PHP?

Tags: php, кэширование

Какие есть способы кэширования данных на PHP?
В частности на обычном хостинге (не выделенный сервер). Нужно для ускорения работы и снижения нагрузки на БД.

Comment: Пробовали http://www.phpfastcache.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать кеш на мемкеше утилитой для ПХП
http://php.net/manual/ru/book.memcache.php

Или можно реализовать файловый кеш, где кешированная информация будет лежать в определенных файликах в файловой системе.

Вот тут есть много библиотек под это дело
https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php#caching